# Wildfly Server brings error code 404 not found

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

i have a project which was running fine in the past. 
But suddenly it doesn't. 
I get the error code HTTP 404 Site not found in Eclipse, also in a browser.

This is my web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/resources</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
<param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
</context-param>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>CardProcessWeb</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>CardProcessWeb</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Also i have restart the Server. Delete it and reconfig, but didn't work.